# An analysis proposition, true or false?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric topological space with $|X|>=\aleph$ (Topological spaces such as $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{Z}$ should not be considered).

Prove or disprove:
If for every uncountable subset $S \subseteq X$, $\mathop{\inf}\limits_{x \neq y,{x,y\in S}}d(x,y)=0$, then $X$ satisfies $C_2$ axiom (or $X$ is separable since such two conceptions are equivalent when $X$ is a metric space).(*)

Below is the remark:

I want to verify it because its converse proposition is true. If an uncountable subset $S \subseteq X$ such that $\mathop{\inf}\limits_{x \neq y,{x,y\in S}}d(x,y)>0$, then $X$ must not be $C_2$. A typical example is $l_{\infty}$, which is formed by bounded series. The subset $Binary$ which is formed by infinite $0-1$ strings is uncountable, and $\mathop{\inf}\limits_{x \neq y,{x,y\in Binary}}d(x,y)=1$ (here distance is induced by $l_{\infty}$ norm), and $l_{\infty}$  is not separable and not a $C_2$ space.

To prove its converse proposition, we notice that：
$X$ is a metric topological space  $\rightarrow$ ($X$ is $C_2$ $\leftrightarrow X$ is separable) is always true. So we only need to prove $X$ is not seperable. Suppose $S$ is an uncountable set and
$m=\mathop{\inf}\limits_{x \neq y,{x,y\in S}}d(x,y)>0$. We can pick neighborhoods $N=\{x \in S|B(x,\frac{m}{3})\}$, those neighborhoods in $N$ do not intersect with each other so $N$ is uncountable. If $A$ is dense in $X$, we assert that every neighborhood in $N$ contains at least one point in $A$, so $|A| \geq |N|$ and $A$ can not be countable.

I really appreciate your help if you prove or disprove (*). If you can prove it in some special cases, I will also thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space satisfying the condition: for every uncountable set $S\subseteq X$ we have $\inf\{d(x,y):x,y\in S,\ x\ne y\}=0.$ I will show that $X$ is separable. (No assumption on the cardinality of $X$ is needed.)

For each $n\in\mathbb N$ let $S_n$ be a maximal subset of $X$ with the property that $x,y\in S,\ x\ne y\implies d(x,y)\ge\frac1n.$ (This requires the axiom of choice, e.g., in the form of Zorn's lemma.) It follows directly from our hypothesis on $(X,d)$ that each $S_n$ is countable; hence the set $S=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}S_n$ is countable. I claim that $S$ is dense in $X.$

Consider any point $x\in X.$ For each $n\in\mathbb N,$ it follows from the maximality of $S_n$ that we can choose a point $x_n\in S_n$ with $d(x_n,x)\lt\frac1n.$ Thus $x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots,x_n,\dots$ is a sequence in $S$ converging to $x.$

Comment: Nice answer! Clear and well written.

Comment: I have not logged in recently,I really appreciate your help.